# WPF UserControl Expose Custom Property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am developing an application following the MVVM model and writing my code in VB.

I have created my own UserControl, let's call it 'Arrow', which has a property in its ViewModel called 'Angle'. In my main window I have a `ListBox` which is bound to a collection and each `ListItem` will be an Arrow.

How can I bind an angle value in the `ListBox`'s `DataSource` to the Angle property of each instance of my UserControl please?

From my research so far it looks as if I need to create a `DependencyProperty` for Angle. If this is the case do I create this in my ViewModel, in the code-behind the XAML or elsewhere?

I'm sure this is simple when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

The `DependencyProperty` would be defined in the UserControl (the code-behind).  You'd then bind that property to the property in the ViewModel

Comment: Thank you, but how would you bind to the ViewModel please? The dependency property would create a new propertyChangedCallback and this method would have to be 'Shared'. Or am I heading in the wrong direction!

Comment: not sure i understand ... if you don't know how to bind a DependencyProperty of a Control to your ViewModel then I don't know how you're using the MVVM pattern. If you need that level of detail, then maybe you should post your code.